# I need to connect a 12V device to Raspberry pi

Tags: switches, raspberry-pi

I need to connect a 16mm press Push Button Switch flat round Latching Self-locking 1NO 1NC with 12V rating to Raspberry pi3. (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/16mm-Metal-brass-Push-Button-Switch-flat-round-illumination-ring-Latching-1NO-1NC-Car-press-button/32639077602.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dekMKgp). How can I do that without blowing up the pi?

Comment: Did you select the 12 volt switch? There is 5V and 6V switches, also.

Comment: Yes I bought that 12V switch. But even if it is 5V or 6V I can't directly connect it to pi right?

Answer (score 0):

The switch part will work fine directly connected to the Raspberry PI GPIO: switches do not make voltage, they only work with what is present. The light part will probably not work well.

If you need the light use a 12V supply. If  you need to blink under software control it use the normal transistor circuit

If you want it to indicate on/off wire the switch contacts to the lamp and a 12V  supply and use the other switch contact (and common) to signal the raspberry pi.

alternatively: 
It may be possible to disassemble the switch and change the resistor so that it will work with the 3.3V signals from the Raspberry Pi.

Or if you can wait a few weeks and $2.25 doesn't break the bank just get the 3V switch that'll work fine unmodified.

Comment: there is no other way other than disassembling?

Comment: if you put 3.3V on the illumination terminals it will glow dimly.  to get full brigthness you need to get more current through the LED, the only way to do that is to increase the voltage or reduce the resistance of the resistor, and that resistor is inside the switch somewhere.  if you only care about "switchness" that part is good already.